# Append 2 fields for host value in Fluentbit running in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, fluentd, fluent-bit

Is it possible to append 2 fields as a value for host in fluentbit. The fluentbit runs as a Daemonset

```yaml
[FILTER]
   Name modify
   Match *
   Add host ${K8S_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

The above has the host with value pertaining to the env var set for K8S_CLUSTER_NAME, I would like to append kubernetes_namespace_name to the above, is it possible to do that?

Comment: Do you want to do something like this  `Add host ${K8S_CLUSTER_NAME} + ${K8S_NAMESPACE_NAME}` ? Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Nope I haven't figured out a solution, just using the K8S_CLUSTER_NAME as host for now...